# Magento admin URL redirecting to index.php/admin, resulting in redirect loop

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, redirect

If I enter URL

```
https://server.com/admin
```

It ends up redirecting to:

```
https://server.com/index.php/admin
```

and I end up with "This webpage has a redirect loop".

a) Is this redirect url correct? Doesn't look to be valid.
b) Where do I correct it?

Comment: My base url in core_config_data is "https://server.com/".  is that correct?

Comment: Did you made any changes to your .htaccess? How does your vhost files look like?

Comment: I think this is normal with magento. Are you saying you cannot login to the admin because of this change url?

Answer (score 2):

/index.php/admin is normal and should work.
Check your Magento .htaccess in root.
Mostly you have to set the web root.

```
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /
```

Your Base URL should be 
http://...

Your secure Base URL should be 
https://...

Comment: I only had trouble with `RewriteBase` and you usually don't need it. `RewriteBase /` is redundant as far as I understand it.

Comment: Which kind of trouble? Did you test it?

Comment: "the rewrite rules don't work" kind of trouble. I don't know which exact setup causes it but I had to remove this line more than once to fix the rewrites.